# Mootools setHtml not working in IE

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to insert HTML into a simple div. The HTML is not making it to the div but if I alert it directly before the setHTML call then it is perfect. The code fails on the setHTML call. Here is the Mootools call:

```
$('vmcartmodule').setHTML(response)
```

The response variable is my HTML gathered from another file.
The error is a Mootools unknown runtime error from here:

```
setHTML: function(){
    this.innerHTML = $A(arguments).join('');
    return this;
}
```

Example of my HTML code:

```
 <div id="opcoCartUpdateTable">
        <div id="row" class="product_row">
        <div class="product_name" >Color: Chocolate Brown<br/> Size: Medium </div>
        <div align="right" class="product_price" >$19.95</div>
        <div class="update_button" ><form method="post" onsubmit="return opcoHandleCartUpdate(this, 0);" style="display: inline;">

    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart" />
    <input type="text" title="Update Quantity In Cart" class="inputbox" size="4" maxlength="4" name="quantity" value="1" />

    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="func" value="cartUpdate" />
    <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="17" />
    <input type="hidden" id="prod_id" name="prod_id" value="17" />
    <!--input type="hidden" id="Itemid" name="Itemid" value="54" /-->
    <input type="hidden" id="Itemid" name="Itemid" value="53" />
    <input type="hidden" id="description" name="description" value="Color:Chocolate_Brown; Size:Medium" />
    <input type="image" name="update" title="Update Quantity In Cart" src="modules/mod_virtuemart_onepagecheckout/assets/images/update_quantity_cart.png" alt="Update" align="middle" onclick="return opcoHandleCartUpdate(this.parentNode, 0);" />
  </form></div>
        <div class="product_price2"  align="right" >$19.95</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Where do I look next? Any help is appreciated. 
thank you

Comment: What is a "Mootools unknow error"? Have you tried to get more info from Firebug or Firefox Error console?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Mootools are you using? In latest versions $A() is deprecated, you should use Array.from().

And the correct way to set HTML for an element is .set('html', yourHtml), an Element method.

Comment: The .set('html', myhtml) method also gives a different error.

Comment: Mootools 1.2. That is all that comes with the version of Joomla that I am using.

Comment: Ah, ok, you are forced to use old version. Ok. Have you tried to check if $('vmcartmodule') is null before the function call?

Answer (score 0):

Okay there were two things going on here that were causing issues with IE. No other browser was being effected and believe me I tried everything that I could find information on. The first was trying to set a form tag using innerHTML, setHTML, or set('html', myhtml). It just will not work on all versions of IE. IE9 and IE10 did have fewer issues, but anything older just will not do it under normal circumstances. Before you suggest creating a form and then filling it dynamically using DOM commands, this situation would not allow me to do that. Most of the page needed to be written dynamically.
  That said, no matter what was attempted either Mootools would send a fatal error or IE would send a fatal error. In my attempts, I saw more than a dozen different errors so further discussion of what the error said would not be helpful at this time. 
  The older version of Mootools did not help (I thought that it was 1.2 but it was 1.1) since most of the literature discusses only the most recent versions. 
  The only solution that worked does not make sense to me, but others have used it and IE liked it. At this point, I was willing to try anything. If you are having the same trouble, I just hope that you have found this page. You need to create a fake element and then replace the real element like this:

```
    oldDiv = document.getElementById('oldIdGoesHere');
    newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "oldIdGoesHere"); 
    // or like this newDiv.id = oldDiv.id;

            //This was my response back from Ajax but it can be 
            //just straight HTML instead of the response variable
    newDiv.innerHTML = response;
    newDiv.className = oldDiv.className;
    oldDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(newDiv, oldDiv);
```

I know...I know...stupid IE. It was truly the only solution in my situation.
Thanks,
Ralph